# lightning:recordForm - New Record doesn't render Compact

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form

I have a lightning recordForm defined as:

```
<lightning:recordForm                                       
        objectApiName="Account"
        layoutType="Compact"
        columns="3"
        mode="edit" />
```

This gives me a form where I can created a new Account.  However it always renders the Full layout.  If I edit an existing record like so:

```
<lightning:recordForm 
        recordId: "0000000000000"                                       
        objectApiName="Account"
        layoutType="Compact"
        columns="3"
        mode="edit" />
```

... it renders the Compact for properly.

Also, if instead of specifying a layout I specify the fields like so:

```
<lightning:recordForm                                       
        objectApiName="Account"
        fields="{v.myFieldList}"
        columns="3"
        mode="edit" />
```

It renders just the specified fields as expected.

Is there some reason that I can't render the Compact layout when creating a new record?

Comment: It does seem that `layoutType=Compact` has no effect while creating a new record